# Fit HLN formula in Origin

Tags: data-analysis, curve-fitting

I have some problems with HLN fitting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUJPw.png)
My formula as shown below (Labtalk script):

psi_deriv=real_polygamma(x,k)

k=0

y=(A*1.23314709*10^-5)*(real_polygamma(0.5+1.64557041*10^(-16)/(x*L^2),1)-ln(1.64557041*10^(-16)/(x*L^2)))

However, when I try to evaluate, the caption says "x, y, A, L not used."
And when I insist to keep fitting, the caption says "Fit did not converge, and reason unknown"

So, I want to know how to deal with this problem, thank you!

I want to fit two parameters: prefactor(A) and phase coherence lengh(L).
I expect the range of A between 1 to -1.
And I only have seven data points for my magneto-conductivity.